# gtkmm: Modal widgets within window

Tags: c++, modal-dialog, gtkmm

I have the following issue: I created a program which prompts the user for some input. This is done using a derived `Gtk::Dialog` that is used like follows:

```
if (modal_dialog->run() == SUCCESS){
  // do stuff depending on modal_dialog inputs here
}
```

Now, I would like to replace the dialog by an embedded widget that is shown within my main window, but acts just like my modal dialog. This means I would like to be able to call something like:

```
if (modal_widget->run == SUCSESS){
  // hide modal widget and do stuff
}
```

Is this easily possible in C++/gtkmm?

*Note:* I managed to get the desired behaviour (it feels the same for the end user) using state variables etc... This means, I manually `show` the wannabe-modal widget, and tell the confirmation button within the wannabe-modal widget to do the rest of the routine (body of the above `if`-statements). However, I'm using the same wannabe-modal widget for different actions, so that I have always to keep track of what I'm doing, which is not very elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `run()` You can create a local loop object and make a nested loop. I don't know gtkmm very well, but the gtk+ code would be:

```
GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
g_main_loop_run(loop);
g_main_loop_unref(loop);
```

Now, in the `clicked` event of your Ok/Cancel buttons simply call `g_main_loop_quit(loop)` and the nested loop will break.

Actually this is, more or less, what the `gtk_dialog_run` function does.

But beware! Your widget `run()` is blocking but not modal, and this is a dangerous beast: any other widget in the application will still be responsible to the user. It is up to you to avoid any undesired reentry.

Comment: Is there a possibility to add some kind of result or return value?

Comment: Well, you need some kind of shared data between the `cliked` events and the `run` function, to get to the loop variable `loop`. Just add one more variable to that shared data, set it to the value you want to return, and return it from the `run` function.